# Why inet_ntoa always returns false IP adresse (socket programming inc )

Tags: c, sockets, server, ip, client

i have simple client/server app with socket , so the client connect to the server with the server ip , i want to return ip of connected client with inet_ntoa but it always returns false ip of connected client. why  ? and how to solve it .

i want the server to return true ip of machine connected to scan open ports later

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct sockaddr_in addr_remote;
...
connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len); 
...
printf( " Welcome %s " , inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));
```

You use `inet_ntoa` with `addr_remote`. `addr_remote` is never set in your code and therefore the contents is kind of unpredictable. You probably intended to use `addr_remote` inside `accept` but you've used `cli` there.